# Goal: Provide a csv listing of users with Display Names that do not match their usernames

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Trying to make a list of users who's names were changed after account creation for various reason (i.e. marriage, etc...)Came across a few ideas, but nothing panned out after I got stumped with Get-ADuser -Filter -Searchbase. Basic idea was to match the users first/last name with the right format for a username ($n = $*.firstname.substring(0,1) + $*.surname) against the current SamAccountUser name. Then that failed so just tried to simplify with matching the last names and getting a list from there.

The code below has no output (meaning that when ran the line is blank). The goal is to provide a listing of users by csv, however I wasn't able to get an output so I haven't gotten that far.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious so any help would be appreciated.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "CN=sample,OU=samples ,DC=sampler,DC=sampling" -Properties SamAccountName, surname | Where-Object {($_.SamAccountName.substring(1)) -ne $_.surname}
```

Comment: What's the point of using `.SubString(1)`? Is there something prepended before the start of the name? If there is no output, that means the criteria isn't/wasn't met. Do you have a "*control*" account that you know is has a changed name?

Comment: We do have a control account that I am using from the OU. It should fulfill the criteria but it does not show up. The standard username convention Tom Hiddleston > thiddleston. Thus removing the first letter of a string has the display last name show the same as the user name w/o the first initial.

Comment: The account you're mentioning would NOT show up since `'Hiddleston' -ne 'thiddleston'.Substring(1)` is __False__

Comment: I'm not seeing how, so if you could point to where I'm off that would be great. I ran this test logic just to make sure: $n = Get-Aduser -Identity 'user' -Properties *
$c = $n.SamAccountname.substring(1)
$d = $n.Surname



if ($d -eq $c){
    write-host "This is True"
} else {
    Write-host "This is False"
    $d
    $c
}
And got This is True.

Comment: you're just reversing the conditional operator, `$n | Where { $_.SamAccountName.substring(1) -ne $_.surname }` will not return anything which is what you're doing right now

Comment: Stating the obvious question, when you run just `Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "CN=sample,OU=samples ,DC=sampler,DC=sampling" -Properties SamAccountName, surname` you get output?

Comment: Does the ```-SearchBase``` parameter even work if you specify a ```CN=```? It's been a while since I've done much with AD / LDAP in PowerShell, but doesn't it need to be the path to  a *container* - i.e. an OU or DC?

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with Compare-Object, that should give you a list of differences (in both ways). If you pipe it to Out-GridView, you can filter it and copy/paste it to Excel.
We use "GivenName"."Surname" as SamAccountName, this has to be edited to your needs.

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com" -Properties SamAccountName,Surname,GivenName

foreach($user in $users)
{
    $compare += Compare-Object -DifferenceObject $user.SamAccountName -ReferenceObject ($user.GivenName + "." + $user.Surname) 
}

$compare | Out-GridView
```